# popup() function always execute the first if statement

Tags: javascript

I have an issue, I can't close the popup, because the else if the statement doesn't execute when the function popup() is invoked always the id="modal1" is executed because it's always true. I wonder how the if statement will be false, so the else if statement will be executed.

```
 <td onclick="popup()"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i></td>
 <div id="modal1" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-wrapper">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div id="popOff1" class="popOff" onclick="popup()">
                                <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                            </div>
                            <video width="550" height="340" controls>
                                <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                Your browser does not support HTML video.
                            </video>
                        </div>
```

js

```
function popup(){
    
    if(document.getElementById("modal1").className === "modal"){
        document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "flex";
        console.log("work");
    }
    // the else if statement doesn't execute!!
    else if(document.getElementById("popOff1").className === "popOff") {
        document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "none";
        console.log("work2");
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use `else if`, rather just have another `if` block

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `if(condition){instructions}`, `if(cond.){instr.} else{instr.}`, or `if(cond.){instr.} else if(cond.){instr.} else{instr.}`, but not `if(cond.){instr.} else if(cond.){instr.}` without else.

It is best practice to code as if it were possible that you make mistakes in reasoning ... It happens ;)
That means: it's possible that we think only two conditions are a possible outcome of our code, but there are more. Therefore, I recommend using this approach:

```
function popup() {
  if (document.getElementById("modal1").className === "modal") {
    document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "flex";
    console.log("work");
  } else if (document.getElementById("popOff1").className === "popOff") {
    document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "none";
    console.log("work2");
  } else {
    console.log("an unforeseen scenario");
  }
}
```

or

```
function popup() {
  if (document.getElementById("modal1").className === "modal") {
    document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "flex";
    console.log("work");
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById("popOff1").className === "popOff") {
      document.getElementById("modal1").style.display = "none";
      console.log("work2");
    }
  }
}
```

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else